# Sig. value missing from ANOVA and model summary tables in SPSS 19.0

Tags: spss

Iam using the SPSS Statistics 19.0 and I run the regression analysis (enter method) for DESHARNAIS dataset.

The problem is that in the ANOVA table appearing in the results the F and Sig do not have any values!!
Also, in the Model summary table the Sig F. Change does not have value either.
What is the problem? 
With other datasets (like COCOMO81, NASA93) I could get values for these.

Please help me

Comment: Please paste the syntax to reproduce the problem.

Comment: When I choose the Enter method to do regression for the DESHARNAIS dataset (found in http://promisedata.org/?cat=11) at the Viewer some tables appear like "Model Summary", "ANOVA", "Descriptive Statistics", "Correlation" etc. The problem is that in the ANOVA table, at the columns F and Sigthere isn't any value. There is only a dot(.). The same thing happens also for the "Model Summary" table. the column of Sig. F.Change has only one dot (.)

Comment: unfortunately i cannot post any images of the tables because iam not permitted (because iam a new user)